# Seeking material on the Lame Principle in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I am looking for some material on Lame Principle in algebraic geometry. I did not find something useful in Internet.

I will be thankful if someone may introduce some materials, papers, books, or sources on it.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is Lame principle?

Comment: I really do not know.  It must be something old. It is related to this paper https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/3613154.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi1p4zrgM3pAhWMK7kGHSaAAAIQFjADegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw05Cey6w_Bb2r226lurByBV

Comment: What language did you originally encounter this concept in?  I would guess that it goes by a different name in English.

Comment: In Portuguese language!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lamé (not Lame!) was a French mathematician, engineer and physicist.   [Here](https://journals.openedition.org/sabix/686) is his detailed biography.
He was a successor of the trio of great French mathematical physicists: Poisson, Fourier, and Laplace.
He studied plane curves of the form $(\frac xa)^r+(\frac ya)^r=1$, where $r$ is not necessarily an integer.
Remind you of something?
Right, he proved the Fermat conjecture (now Wiles-Taylor theorem) for $n=7$.
Engineers were pretty good in those times!

Comment: Thanks a lot.  some friend asked me about it. She should prepare it for teaching stage of some entrance exam.  Would you suggest some material for this means?